# What is the current state of art reporting and charting tool in Java web applications?

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, jasper-reports, birt, pentaho

We are looking to integrate a reporting and charting tool in our web application. The web application is based on GWT, Spring and Hibernate. The candidates that we are evaluating are

```
   - BIRT 
   - Jasper Report 
   - Pentaho 
    - Crystal Report (It's not free, but being free is not the 
                      highest priority for the project).
```

Some of the features that we are looking for 
- How well it can integrate with the technology stack? 
- How easy it is to design new reports. We want our not so technical customer to be able to do it easily?

Any insight, links experiences would be helpful.

Comment: one interesting link is http://www.innoventsolutions.com/birt-jasper-pentaho-comparison-matrix.html

Answer (score 0):

GWT, Hibernate and JasperReports make a perfect stack.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Windward Reports](http://www.windwardreports.com/). Without knowing more about the type of reports you need, I can't say for sure if it will be better, but in most cases it saves a lot of time over alternatives. And you can do more with it.

The unique difference is with Windward you design the reports in Microsoft Word, Excel, or PowerPoint. So it's a very powerful easy to use design tool you already know. And because Word/Excel/PPT are free-form, [you can do most anything for your final report](http://blogs.windwardreports.com/davidt/2011/01/banded-reports-are-evil.html).